# How to get all CheckBoxes using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In `Asp.net`. how can I access every `checkbox` exists in the page using `C#` code ?

Comment: You can access checkboxes via their IDs if they are server-control.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This gets you every `Checkbox` on the page. You can change the `form1` to whatever control you want to search inside of.

```
foreach (Control ctl in form1.Controls)
{
    if (ctl is CheckBox)
    {

    }
}
```

Alternatively if you know the ID of the control:

```
form1.FindControl("id");
```